# “Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Tags: python, indentation

I'm having the error: "Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level" thrown in this section of my file on line 10. I've tried re-indenting all of it but I can't find the reason as to why it's throwing this error here:

```
import os
import time


if not os.path.exists("Desktop/ServerNotify/ServerNotifier.txt"):
    os.makedirs("Desktop/ServerNotify/ServerNotifier.txt")

def WriteAddressToFile():
    theFile = open("ServerList.txt")

  for line in theFile:
    if line == server:
      theFile.close()
    else:
      theFile.close()

      theFile = open("ServerList.txt", "a")
      theFile.write(server + "\n")
      theFile.close()
```

Comment: so here you go, ``    theFile`` and ``  for line`` are not indented equally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for-block needs to be indented by two spaces:

```
def WriteAddressToFile():
    theFile = open("ServerList.txt")

    for line in theFile:
      if line == server:
        theFile.close()
      else:
        theFile.close()

        theFile = open("ServerList.txt", "a")
        theFile.write(server + "\n")
        theFile.close()
```

Notice how it now lines up with this line:

```
theFile = open("ServerList.txt")
```

Also, just a little nag, the Python standard for indenting is 4 spaces. :)